# React JSX issue

Tags: reactjs, forms

I'm trying out React for the first time and I'm trying to render a class within another class and the react component doesn't seem to be showing up on the webpage. I'm not sure exactly is going wrong. If anyone can help me that would be great!

This is one of my js files

```
class PersonalDetails extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      email: "",
      mobile: ""
    };
  }


  render() {
    const { firstName, lastName, email, mobile } = this.state;
    const { handleChange } = this.props;
    return (
      <form>
        <div class="name">
          <label>First Name</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={firstName}
            onChange={handleChange("firstName")}
          ></input>
          <label>Last Name</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={lastName}
            onChange={handleChange("lastName")}
          ></input>
        </div>
        <div class="contact-info">
          <label>Email</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={email}
            onChange={handleChange("email")}
          ></input>
          <label>Mobile Number</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={mobile}
            onChange={handleChange("mobile")}
          ></input>
        </div>
        <button>Next</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default PersonalDetails;
```

I'm using the above  class within this one

```
import PersonalDetails from "./personal_details";

class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      step: 1 // keep track of which form to show
    };
  }

  // increment step
  nextStep = () => {
    const { step } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      step: step + 1
    });
  };

  prevStep = () => {
    const { step } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      step: step - 1
    });
  };

  // handle all field changes
  handleChange = input => event => {
    this.setState({
      [input]: event.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { step } = this.state;
    switch (step) {
      case 1:
        return (
          <PersonalDetails
            handleChange={this.handleChange} // attributes passed down are props
            nextStep={this.nextStep}
          />
        );
      case 2:
        return <h1>Location</h1>;
      case 3:
        return <h1>Selling</h1>;
      case 4:
        return <h1>Learning </h1>;
      case 5:
        return <h1>Buying</h1>;
    }
  }
}

let domContainer = document.querySelector("#form_container");
ReactDOM.render(<Form />, domContainer);
```

(I'm going to change the h1 tags with components later on)
And this is my HTML file

```
<!-- REACT -->
    <div id="form_container"></div>              
    <!-- Load React. -->
    <!-- Note: when deploying, replace "development.js" with "production.min.js". -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <!-- To use JSX -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Load our React component. -->
    <script src="form.js"></script>
    <!-- REACT -->
```

Comment: there is nothing wrong with your code. Do you get any errors?

Comment: I don't get any errors, but nothing is popping up on the webpage either

Comment: i copy pasted your code in codesandbox and it works - https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-brahmagupta-m4w9j?file=/src/index.js